# Connecting Jitterbit to Heroku Postgre

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, jitterbit

I'm trying to connect to Heroku Postgre using Jitterbit Cloud Data Loader.

got my connection parameters all setup but unfortunately I run into an error **FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "210.213.78.5", user "u49bh1311s0496", database "dfsj8qbgvj0ram", SSL off**

Would like to ask for possible solution with this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you getting that from Jitterbit?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I connect remotely to a Heroku Postgresql database, I need to have SSL on.

You'd typically connect using the heroku domain name instead of an IP as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your connection string:

jdbc:postgresql://210.213.78.5:5432/dfsj8qbgvj0ram?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory

with your username and password.